# Realm.io - How to use wildcard in query?

Tags: android, wildcard, realm

According to [this cheatsheet](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/), Realm does not support wildcard. Is there any way to use wildcard with Realm.io?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Joe, that's not supported yet. I suggest you create a github issue feature request and track progress there.